# Export To Excel

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view. Am trying to export in the excel.
The code is as follows :

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control gvReport1)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=Report.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
        gvReport1.RenderControl(htextw);
        Response.Write(stw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Now the problem is that an excel file is opening but data is not getting displayed. I guess the data is not getting read, and the more wierd thing is that I have two web pages. In the first webpage the export to excel is working properly, but on the second page it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

> There's probably a more elegant way...

There is.

Have a look at this:
[Export to Excel library](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

It's a completely free library which uses Microsoft's Open XML libraries to create a genuine Excel 2007 .xlsx file.

All *you* have to do is call one "**CreateExcelDocument**" function, and pass in the DataTable, DataSet or List<> which contains the data you're using to fill your GridView.

```
// Step 1: Create a DataSet, and put some sample data in it
DataSet ds = CreateSampleData();

// Step 2: Create the Excel .xlsx file
try
{
    string excelFilename = "C:\\Sample.xlsx";
    CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, excelFilename);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't create Excel file.\r\nException: " + ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

Enjoy, and good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write(stw.ToString());
```

Is incorrect, this will just return the type name, you need to write the output of RenderControl to a string first, then write the string content using Response.Write().

EDIT: Here is an example of how you could get the content of a rendered control:

```
     // Obtain the content about to be rendered.
     var ms = new MemoryStream();
     var w = new StreamWriter(ms);
     var r = new StreamReader(ms);
     using (var htmlw = new HtmlTextWriter(w))
     {
        gvReport1.RenderControl(htmlw);
        htmlw.Flush();
     }

     ms.Position = 0;
     var content = r.ReadToEnd();
     r.Close();
```

There's probably a more elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find what you search on here :

```
.doc


application/msword

.dot


application/msword

.docx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

.dotx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template

.docm


application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12

.dotm


application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12

.xls


application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlt


application/vnd.ms-excel

.xla


application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlsx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

.xltx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template

.xlsm


application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12

.xltm


application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12

.xlam


application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12

.xlsb


application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12

.ppt


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pot


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pps


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.ppa


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pptx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

.potx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template

.ppsx


application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow

.ppam


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12

.pptm


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12

.potm


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12

.ppsm


application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
```